# Creating dropdown list from related table yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have two tables: *product* and *product_type* (related to the models resp. Product and Product_type):

```
product : product_id, product_type_id, name, etc...
product_type : product_type_id, name, desc, etc...
```

Both are related with key "product_type_id".

I have created the crud for both tables using gii crud generator. Now on Product form page I want to display the listing of all product_type name in dropdown field using Yii ActiveRecord. I have added this line in *views/product/_form.php* script:

```
<?php
    $list = CHtml::listData(ProductType::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'product_type_name')), 'id', 'id');
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'product_type_id', $list);
?>
```

But it's showing blank dropdown field :(

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved MySelf :)

By just providing product_type_name.

```
<?php
        $list = CHtml::listData(ProductType::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'product_type_name')), 'product_type_id', 'product_type_name');
        echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'product_type_id', $list);
        ?>
```

Comment: I use this solution and it works. But if product_type_id is null, then it will show the 1st item of product_type_name. Is it possible to just show an empty?

Answer (score 5):

In [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html) the class *CHtml* does not exist anymore. 
Below is a solution, based on the following assumptions:

- The [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html) framework is used;
- The table *product_type* is associated with the model *Product_type*;
- The *product_type* table has a field called "*type-name*".

```
     <?php
         // get all product types from the corresponding table:
         $productTypes = Product_type::find()->orderBy('type-name')->asArray()->all(); 
         // create an array of pairs ('id', 'type-name'):
         $productTypeList = ArrayHelper::map($productTypes, 'id', 'type-name'); 
         // finally create the drop-down list:
         $form->field($model, 'product_type_id')->dropDownList($productTypeList) 
     ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your code like bellow

```
    <?php
    $list = CHtml::listData(ProductType::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'product_type_name')), 'table_col_name1', 'table_col_name2'); //table_col_name1 is value of option, table_col_name2 is label of option
    // echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'product_type_id', $list);
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('name_of_the_dropdown', $model, $list);
    ?>
```