# Creating dropdown list from related table

Tags: yii

I have a two tables:

```
tbl_day:id_day,mon,tues,wed,thurs,fri,sat,sun
tbl_shft:shft_id,start,end,name,status
```

I want to have a dropdown table in tbl_day where mon is dependent in the tbl_shft name.

I come up with a dropdown that is displaying data from shift. what I did is.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sun'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'sun',$model -> getCategories(),array('prompt'=>'Select a Shift'))
?>
```

and for my model

```
public function getCategories(){
//this function returns the list of categories to use in a dropdown
return CHtml::listData(Shift::model()->findAll(), 'shft_id', 'name');}
```

My problem is that **it is not submitting.** I dont know where my problem here is. Im a beginner in Yii. Hope someone helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not submitting in sense what you are not getting the selected shift_id ??

Comment: maybe. whenever I click submit it does not do anything. Its my first time doing this. I dont know if my action create will do. I did not do anything with my actionCreate

Comment: Print out `$_POST` in controller where you're handling it. It will be clear what is actually submitted. Also it's a good idea to check generated HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500322/creating-dropdown-list-from-related-table-yii

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500322/creating-dropdown-list-from-related-table-yii
may be this help you

Answer (score 0):

In here your code will work. I think the submitted output was not handled correctly. @sam dark says correctly. Edit your question .just place the controller action of your process . Else you just place this code on your controller action. And give the result of controller on this question itself.

```
Public function actionYouraction(){
......
if(isset($_POST))
{
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
   exit(); }      }
```